# In Swift, why subclass method cannot override the one, provided by protocol extension in superclass

Tags: swift, protocols, swift2, xcode7

I know the title of this question is confusing but the weird behaviour is explained in the example below:

```
protocol Protocol {
    func method() -> String
}

extension Protocol {
    func method() -> String {
        return "From Base"
    }
}

class SuperClass: Protocol {
}

class SubClass: SuperClass {
    func method() -> String {
        return "From Class2"
    }
}

let c1: Protocol = SuperClass()
c1.method() // "From Base"
let c2: Protocol = SubClass()
c2.method() // "From Base"
```

How come `c1.method()` and `c2.method()` return the same? How come the `method()` in SubClass doesn't work?

Interestingly, without declaring the type of c2, this is going to work:

```
let c2  = SubClass()
c2.method() // "From Class2"
```

Comment: nice question. I got a similar one at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702738/method-customization-in-sub-class-not-called ;). Which is possibly a duplicate of yours. It is like the dynamic dispatch can only work if the SuperClass does implement the function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `c1` and `c2` are of type `Protocol`, as you've defined their type explicitly this way (remember: protocols are fully fledged types). This means, when calling `method()`, Swift calls `Protocol.method`.

---

If you define something like:

```
let c3 = SuperClass()
```

...`c3` is of type `SuperClass`. As `SuperClass` has no more specific `method()` declaration, `Protocol.method()` is still used, when calling `c3.method()`.

---

If you define something like:

```
let c4 = SubClass()
```

...`c4` is of type `SubClass`. As `SubClass` does have a more specific `method()` declaration, `SubClass.method()` is used, when calling `c4.method()`.

---

You could also get `c2` to call `SubClass.method()`, by down-casting it to `SubClass:

```
(c2 as! SubClass).method() // returns "From Class2"
```

---

Here's a demonstration on [SwiftStub](http://swiftstub.com/208661692/?v=beta).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I add SubClass2 (conforms to Protocol directly) and c5 on http://swiftstub.com/452669817/?v=beta. You see, once c5 conforms Protocol directly not via inheritance or super class, even if I cast c5 as Protocol, it will still use SubClass2's method implementation, instead of the default one from protocol extension. It's just not very intuitive to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure of the underlying mechanism but it must be something to do with the fact that protocols don't necessarily allow for inheritance.

One way to work around this problem is by also adding the method to `SuperClass`

```
import Foundation
protocol Protocol: class {
    func method() -> String
}

extension Protocol {
    func method() -> String {
        return "From Base"
    }
}

class SuperClass: Protocol {
    func method() -> String {
        return "From Super"
        }
}

class SubClass: SuperClass {
    override func method() -> String {
        return "From Class2"
    }
}

let c1: Protocol = SuperClass()
c1.method() // "From Super"
let c2: Protocol = SubClass()
c2.method() // "From Class2"
```

Comment: yes it is a workaround. I was just curious why it doesn't work if there's no implementation in SuperClass

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes, if there is a superclass that conforms to the protocol but doesn't provide an implementation for it, the protocol extension's implementation will be available in subclasses, even if the sublcasses have implementation (however they have to be casted to the superclass's or to the protocol's type).

However, if the superclass has an implementation of the protocol's method, then protocol's implementation won't be available from neither the superclass nor it's subclasses.

Comment: thank you for the answer. If SubClass is not a subclass of SuperClass, but just conforms to Protocol, like "class SubClass: Protocol {}". Then let c2: Protocol = SubClass(), c2.method() // From Class2, even if I cases c2 as Protocol. So my current conclusion, on top of your statement is, "sub classes cannot override super class methods provided by protocol" extensions.

Comment: @aquajach Good observation, I rewrote my answer according to it.